# How do I connect a control in my WPF View to my ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So specifically, it's a WebBrowser control (though I suspect most controls will need a similar setup), that I'm trying to get to display the contents of an Epub file. I've got the library to extract the Epub (VersOne) and I can read the contents to, say, a string for example. My problem has less to do with the filetypes involved, and more with just trying to figure out WPF.

Here's my View (still very basic):

```
<Window x:Class="EpubDisplay_wpf.Views.ReaderView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EpubDisplay_wpf.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ReaderView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser x:Name="EpubWindow" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and then the code-behind:

```
public partial class ReaderView : Window
{
    public ReaderView(string filepath)
    {
         InitializeComponent();        
         this.DataContext = new ReaderViewModel(EpubWindow, filepath);
        
    }
}
```

Now, thanks to someone else's post, I figured out that at a basic level, I had the InitializeComponent() line and this.DataContext... line reversed, which wasn't working at all. Now I've got that fixed, I'm wondering what a better way would be. This doesn't seem like a really scalable way to link the View and ViewModel, passing the control directly via the constructor. I've seen solutions to similar problems using OnPropertyChanged events, AttachedProperty, and probably several others as well. So obviously this is a problem with multiple potential solutions. I'm just not sure what the best solution is, and what I've found doesn't seem to be sufficiently similar for me to understand. So I'd appreciate some guidance here.

Comment: It is unclear why you set the Window's DataContext at all. There is not data binding in the XAML you are showing. Then you are passing a reference to the WebBrowser element to the view model. That is not MVVM. View models have no knowledge of the view.

Comment: This is still at a very basic level. I set the DataContet because A, I thought you had to, and B, I anticipate using Data Binding later on. What would you suggest is the best way to accomplish this without passing the reference to the WebBrowser control to the ViewModel?

Comment: I would probably encapsulate all the WebBrowser related code in a UserControl. It could have a bindable property, i.e. a dependency property that would be bound to either the file path or some kind of a document abstraction. Hard to tell without knowing more detail about your code.

Answer (score 0):

My common approach is to set create the datacontext at that moment just before you show your view. So if this is the Main-Window of your application I would go to the App.cs-File an remove the Startup-Uri, subscribe to the Startup-Event and in the EventHandler there i would do the following:

```
ReaderViewModel viewModel = new ReaderViewModel();
ReaderView view = new ReaderView
{
  DataContext = viewModel 
};
view.ShowDialog();
```

If you need a parameter in your viewmodel you can pass it as constructor-parameter to it.

Comment: While this is generally ok, it would not work here, since OP is passing a child element of the ReaderView to the ReaderViewModel.